# Emacs Lisp: Convert List to String

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am dabbling in Emacs Lisp and I am trying to write the following function:

```
(defun buffer-file-name-body ()
  (last (split-string (buffer-file-name) "/")))
```

What I am trying to achieve is to extract just the file name and extension from the full path given by `(buffer-file-name)`. However, this implementation returns a list of one item `("scratch.el")` ... I tried several things such as passing the result of `(last)` through `(string)` but that raises an error... Google did not return anything useful when I searched for *Emacs List convert list to string*. How to I do this?

Comment: do you mean you have a list '("scranch.el") and you need to extract "scratch.el" from it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct... would a simple CAR suffice?

Comment: Yes, it does I just tested it

Comment: If you've hit upon (car (last ...)), then you're in good shape, I think.  For other Emacs lisp questions, you might want to check out the EmacsWiki for some useful tips:  http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc56

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check out the built-in function `file-name-nondirectory`. (Also, if you allow me the small hint, your function will barf on buffers that do not visit a file, such as e.g., \*scratch\*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you want is `(file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))` which returns the simple file name, sans any directory information, as a string.

Comment: Although the original question was around converting a List to a String and CAR would be a good solution, using `(file-name-nondirectory)` applies better to this situation and is the cleanner solution...

Comment: @HowardWest Hey mate, nice piggy backing on my comment above. Please note again that `(buffer-file-name)` returns `nil` for buffers not visiting a file, and that `file-name-nondirectory` cannot handle a `nil` argument.

Comment: @Thomas If you answer the question, I will give you accepted answer for it... :)

Comment: @JonasGorauskas Ah, don't worry about it. I honestly think it's not even the correct answer to your actual question, because it doesn't tell you how to extract a string value from a list. It might have been what you were after, but it doesn't answer what you asked about. If anything, fvwmer should get the credit since he gave the correct answer to that.

Comment: I took this to be the question:  "What I am trying to achieve is to extract just the file name and extension from the full path given by (buffer-file-name)"

Comment: Gosh. my ex-expression is also `(last (split-string ` to get filename only. `file-name-nondirectory` saved my life.